custom bib style with biblatex and lualatex, author in smallcaps, title in italics, or emph
I would like to have my citations and the bibliography with authors in smallcaps and titles in italics. Is there a biblatex style for it? Or can one make one in the simplest possible way?
I compile my files with texshop and in the preamble I have
% Bibliography setup
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=verbose-ibid]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\addbibresource{bibteologia.bib}

Many thanks!

why backend=bibtex? if using biblatex it's a lot nore natural to use the default biber

I use bibtex because Texshop does not have biber.

texshop is just an editor it doesn't have bibtex or biber or latex. Those programs come from your tex distribution and all tex distributions include biber and bibtex unless you have some custom minimal install that does not include some default programs, do you use texlive or miktex?

I looked in the settings of Texshop and I found:
pdflatexmk  ... doest that answer your question?
In any case my question was about the bibstyle, possibly without changing any setting in texshop, given that I am very clumsy ...

no pdlatexmk is another program that comes with both texlive and miktex and is essentially unrelated to texshop other than, like most editors, texshop lets you specify external programs to call.  The features of biblatex are restricted (in general not necessarily for this) if things need to work with the legacy bibtex backend  which is why I asked why you were using bibtex here as it will potentially affect the possible answers. It still seems most likely that you have biber installed and don't need to force bibtex compatibility.

@Ste64 - Precisely because your question is about modifying parts of the workings of biblatex, you should not needlessly limit what can be done by imposing the restriction that the solution has to use BibTeX instead of biber as the backend.

"title" is ill-defined. Most bibliography styles distinguish (at least) two types of titles: titles of books and journals (often set in italics) and titles of articles in journals or collections (usually not in italics, and often enclosed in quotation marks). And titles of theses some times pattern like the former and sometimes like the latter. Bibliography styles are complex, and so your question is really not clear enough for people to give you a solution.

I asked chat gpt and it gave me the answer below, that works.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex} % You can change the style if needed
\addbibresource{yourbibliography.bib}
% Author names in small caps
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\renewcommand{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
% Titles in italics
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,book,inbook,incollection,inproceedings,thesis,unpublished]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{journaltitle}{#1} % Prevents journal titles from being italicized
